# Searching a txt file for a string and then counting how many times it appears

Tags: c

I am trying to read my file "text.txt", and then count how many times my string has been found in that file. I am then trying to write the results into the file "results.txt".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

//Our main function
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int num = 0;

    //this sets the max value of our string to 300 characters
    char str[300];

    //this prints the statement requesting the input from the user
    printf("Enter a Sentence or Phrase: ");

    //assigns the string that the user just inputted into our variable "str"
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
    printf("This is What you entered:  %s", str);

    //this opens our "text.txt" file and reads it
    FILE *in_file = fopen("text.txt", "r"); //read only
    FILE *out_file = fopen("result.txt", "w"); //write only

    //tests if the txt file exists
    if (in_file == NULL || out_file == NULL) 
        {
            printf("Error! Could not open file\n");
            exit(-1); 
       }

    fprintf(out_file, "%s", str); //Write to file
    fclose(out_file);
```

I have used the following method but it does not seem to work

```
    while(fscan(in_file, "%s", str) == 1)
    {
       if(strstr("%s", str)!=0)//if match is found then increment the counter
      { 
           num++;
       }
    }

    fprintf(in_file, "We found the word %s in the file %d times\n",str,num);
    num = 0;

   
}
```

Comment: Removing the C++ tag unless there's some relevance here.

Comment: `fscan()`? What's that?

Comment: Can you explain "does not seem to work" in more technical terms?

Comment: You might review some documentation for `strstr`. If you're asking the user for a sentence are you looking for instances of that complete sentence in the file or how many words in the file appear in the sentence? The trailing `s` doesn't belong in this format string `scanf("%[^\n]s", str);`.

Comment: would fgets work instead of fscan?

Comment: I am asking the user for a sentence, and then searching that file for the same sentence.

Comment: The C standard library does not have a function called `fscan`. Do you mean `fscanf`?

Comment: `fprintf(in_file, ...` How is THAT supposed to work? (Outputting to a file opened to read.)

Comment: whoops... @Fe2O3

Comment: In more technical terms, the code does not do anything, but it also does not give me an error either. I do not know exactly what it is doing or why it is not working. It is simply "not working".

Comment: Dylan de Hoyos If the file was "aaaaa", does "aaaa" occur once or twice?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use a width limit, drop `s`**

Avoid overruns, `s` serves no propose.  Check return value;

```
// scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
if (scanf("%299[^\n]", str) != 1) {
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

**Test each line**

Look for multiple occurrences of `str`.

```
char buffer[4096];
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, in_file)) {
  char *p = buffer;
  char *q;
  while ((q = strstr(p, str)) != NULL) {
    num++;
    p = q + 1;  // Look again.
  }
}
```

Comment: so now that we've counted how many times that phrase is in the text.txt file, how would i go about printing the words that are in both the string and the text.txt file to print in all caps?

Comment: what if the searched text is crossing the buffer size boundary

Comment: @rioV8 As long as file lines are < `sizeof buffer` all but maybe the last line will contains a `'\n'`.  Since OP's `str` never contains a `'\n'`, the pattern will not wrap around the end of a line into the next line.  For longer lines or other patterns, additional code needed.

Comment: could you explain this code a little more about what it is doing?

Comment: @DylandeHoyos `strstr(p, str)` searches `p` for the pattern stored in `str`.  If found, `q` points to the someplace in `p`, then the search happens again at the starting at the next character.  If not found `q` is `NULL` and searching stops.